# Making a basic poll with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just starting to learn javascript/jquery.

For my most recent task I've been asked to create a function that listens for clicks on two buttons and looks at the "`data-vote`" attribute to see what was voted for.

I need to set up an event listener on buttons with the '`vote`' class, both of which also have a '`data-vote`' attribute, one is '`great`', the other '`greatest`'. When one of those `buttons` is clicked I need to look at that attribute to determine which it was, and then increment a counter for the affected tally.

I know this seems simple, but I'm very lost. Here's my code so far :

```
$('.vote').on('click', function(event){
   var targetElement = event.target;
   $(targetElement).find('data-vote').each(function(){
       if .attr(great)
```

Any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var great = 0;
var greatest = 0;

$('.vote').on('click', function() {
  var value = $(this).data('vote');

  if(value === 'great') {
    great++;
  } else if(value === 'greatest') {
    greatest++;
  }
});
```

The key here is that inside the `click` handler, `$(this)` usually refers to the element you clicked.

You can just query for the attribute `data-vote` and do something with that value. Notice we're using jQuery's [`data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method, which queries for HTML5 `data-*` attributes.

To increment counters, you can just use two global variables `great` and `greatest`. Depending on the value of `data-vote` of the button you clicked, you can just increment the corresponding global variable using the `++` operator (this is called the [increment arithmetic operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment)). This is an atomic operator that mutates the value in place.

Comment: You can also use $(this).data('vote') as a shortcut for data attributes.

Comment: @Rob, thanks, just changed that right when you commented! lol